# Argparse and return types

Tags: python, socket.io

I;m pretty new to this stuff, but I'm working on a programme which would connect with car drive simulator, but I'm getting such output:

> File "C:/Users/martin/Desktop/AD/drive.py", line 95, in module
>
> with open(args.model, 'r') as jfile:
>
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

The question is how to fix it?

My code:

```
import argparse
import base64
import json
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socketio
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from io import BytesIO
from time import gmtime, strftime
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import model_from_json

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)
model = None
prev_image_array = None

@sio.on('telemetry')
def telemetry(sid, data):
    # some code here

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environment):
    # some code here

def send_control(steering_angle, throttle):
    sio.emit("steer", data={
        'steering_angle': steering_angle.__str__(),
        'throttle': throttle.__str__()
    }, skip_sid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='AD')
    parser.add_argument('--model', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
    with open(args.model, 'r') as jfile:
        model = model_from_json(json.load(jfile))

    model.compile("adam", "mse")
    weights_file = args.model.replace('json', 'h5')
    model.load_weights(weights_file)

    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 4567)), app)
```

Comment: Are you passing the necessary arguments when running this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run the script with necessary command line arguments -

In this case, there seems to be only 1 argument `--model`

so you will need to do something like this -

```
$ python3 so-p2.py --model "Model"
Model
```

In general, you can find out all necessary arguments by passing help -

```
$ python3 so-p2.py --help
usage: so-p2.py [-h] [--model MODEL]

AD

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --model MODEL
```

Comment: Please provide  the arguments that you are passing to the script. If possible, like how i showed in the answer above.

Comment: But if I may ask one more question I would be really grateful. When I ran this programme the way you showed me it said there is no module called socketio, but I have installed it. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Glad to know that it works! Absence of module will lead to errors and the only thing to do in that case is to install the required module(s). The right way to manage the dependencies is to have a requirements.txt file that will have all dependencies. You can get this via runnning pip feeze command. Then people can run pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your help!